# Global maximum and minimum on a sphere

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ and i have $T=C(x^2+2y^2+3z^2+2xy+2xz)$ temperature function. I need to find maximum and minimum of this temperature function.
First i tried to calculate $\partial_x f=2x$,
$ \partial_y f=2x$,
$ \partial_z f=2z $

$\partial_x T=2x+2y+2z $, $\partial_y T=4y+2x $, $\partial_z T=6z+2x $

Then I equate them $2x=\lambda(2x+2y+2z)$, $2y=\lambda(4y+2x)$, $2x=\lambda(6z+2x)$

But I cannot find lambda from here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T=C(x^2+2y^2+3z^2+2xy+2xz)$

As $C$ is a constant, we take $f(x,y,z) = x^2+2y^2+3z^2+2xy+2xz$

where $g(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2 - R^2 = 0$

$f(x,y,z) = \lambda g(x,y,z)$

Taking derivatives wrt $x,y,z$,

$(1-\lambda)x+y+z = 0$ ...(i)

$x + (2-\lambda)y = 0$ ...(ii)

$x + (3-\lambda)z = 0$ ...(iii)

From $(ii)$ and $(iii)$,

$y = -\frac{x}{2-\lambda}, z = -\frac{x}{3-\lambda}$ (for $\lambda \ne 2,3$)

Plugging into $(i)$,

$((1-\lambda)(2-\lambda)(3-\lambda) + 2\lambda - 5)x=0$

So either $x=0$ or

$-\lambda^3+6\lambda^2-9\lambda+1=0$ ($x\ne 0$)

$\lambda \approx 0.12061, 2.3473, 3.5321$.

We already know $y, z$ in terms of $x$ and $\lambda$. Plugging these values and using the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ will give us possible values of $x$ and from there onx, values of $y, z$. We then need to check these critical points for maxima and minima.

Comment: here i got 3 values for y and 3 values for z depending on x. So I have to put them into $x^2+y^2+z^2-R^2=0$ and find 3 different values right?

Comment: Yes in fact you will get more points as you will get both $\pm$ values for $x$ and so also for $y$ and $z$.

Comment: yeah i found $(x,-x/1.87939,-x2,87939)$, $(x,x/0.3473,-x/0.6527)$, $(x,x/1.5321,x/0.5321)$

Comment: and these values are not point. These are lines, so I have 3 lines. One will be maxima and other one will ve minimum

Comment: Yes seems correct. These are not points but once you plug them into $x^2+y^2+z^2 = R^2$, you will get critical points in terms of $R$. If you take the first one for example, $(x, -x/1.87939,-x/2,87939)$, you get $x \approx \pm 0.844R$.

Comment: ah okay, now i understand. Thanks for your help

Comment: I want to ask something. Are the maximum and minimum points are these values of $(x,−x/1.87939,−x/2,87939)$ , $(x,x/0.3473,−x/0.6527)$, $(x,x/1.5321,x/0.5321)$ ? or it's just R values?

Comment: Once you plug in the constraint and find value of $x$ in terms of $R$ and plug in the above, those are your critical points. But you need to check which one maximizes your function and which one minimizes your function.

Comment: For the first one we got $x \approx \pm 0.844R$. For $x = 0.844R, y = - 0.844R / 1.87939, z = - 0.844R / 2.87939.$ Similarly, for $x = - 0.844R, y = 0.844R / 1.87939, z = 0.844R / 2.87939$. So you have two critical points from the first one:  ($0.844R, - 0.844R / 1.87939, - 0.844R / 2.87939$) and ($ - 0.844R, 0.844R / 1.87939, 0.844R / 2.87939$). Similarly you will get critical points from other two. These should be plugged into the function to find value of function at these critical points and see which is max and min.